# function handles in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a question regarding function(handles) in Octave.
So, I want to call a function, which accepts two variables and returns two(the implementation is faulty; but not relevant in this case).

According to the documentation this should be quite straightforward:

> function [ret-list] = name (arg-list)
>
> body
>
> endfunction

I'm trying the following:

```
function two_d_comp = twodcomp 
twodcomp.twoDperp=@perp;
                 ^
end

function twoDperp[vmag, vangle]=perp(x,y)
W = hypot(y,x);
vmag = y/W;
vangle = x/y;
end;
```

I saved the function in a file called twodcomp.m.
When I call the function as follows:

```
[X, Y] = twodcomp.twoDperp(1,2)
```

Octave spits out the following:

```
error: @perp: no function and no method found
error: called from
twodcomp at line 2 column 20
```

I managed to remove the error by removing the output arguments vmag and vangle, as follows:

```
function twoDperp=perp(x,y)
```

But this is obviously not really what I want.
Do you guys happen to have some pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: As the doc specifies the syntax as: `function [ret-list] = name (arg-list)`,  with this `function twodcomp = twodcomp` the output of your function is twodcomp and the name of your function is also `twodcomp`. There are no input arguments. In the second function, `function twoDperp[vmag, vangle]=perp(x,y)`  `twoDperp[vmag, vangle]` is not a valid syntax. It can either be `[vmag,vangle]` or `twoDperp`. From the look of your code, it seems that you want to use  `[vmag,vangle]`. Also I have no idea what you're trying to do with `twodcomp.twoDperp=@perp;`

Comment: They are called anonymous functions, I have linked to the MATLAB and Octave documentation for them in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial function `twodcomp`: you cannot have the output variable (before the `=`) be named the same as your function name (after the `=`).

Then if you want to assign an anonymous function ([MATLAB docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), [Octave docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Anonymous-Functions.html)) using the `@` notation, you can still pass the desired inputs.

So rewrite it like:

```
% Include empty parentheses after a function name to make it clear which is the output
function output = twodcomp()
    % Not sure why you're assigning this function to a struct, but
    % still give yourself the ability to pass arguments.
    % I'm assuming you want to use the output variable, 
    % and not reuse the main function name (again) 
    output.twoDperp = @(x,y) perp(x,y);                     
end
```

With your second function, you just need to remove the `twoDperp` before your output arguments. In your question you state the expected syntax from the docs, but then didn't follow it...

```
function [vmag, vangle] = perp(x,y)
    W = hypot(y,x);
    vmag = y/W;
    vangle = x/y;
end
```

Now these can be used like so:

```
% Deliberately using different variable names to make it clear where things
% overlap from the function output. twodcomp output is some struct.
myStruct = twodcomp();
% The output struct has the field "twoDperp" which is a function with 2 outputs
[m, a] = myStruct.twoDperp(1,2);
```